# Building User Activity Cohorts

Tags: r

Thank you for your help - I am trying to build cohorts.

And I do get what I am looking for with ...

```
cohort3 <- transactions %>%
group_by(userId) %>%
mutate(first_transaction = min(createDate)) %>%
group_by(first_transaction, createDate) %>%
summarize(clients = n())
```

[image]

BUT ... as you can see by the result, I get data back for every single day.

We had 7 users that transacted on 2017-01-03 the first time.
2 of these users transacted on 2017-01-04.
4 of these users transacted on 2017-01-05 and so forth.

This is great - but it's too granular.
How do I modify the above code to summarize by month or better quarter?

Like:
Jan-2017 - 25 users transacted the first time.
Feb-2017 - 12 users from that cohort transacted again ... and so on.

Even better.
Q1 2017 - 78 users transacted.
Q2 2017 - 35 users of that Q1 2017 cohort transacted. etc

Thank you.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package includes a `quarter()` function for determining what quarter of the year a given date falls into. Something along these lines should do what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

cohort3 <- 
  transactions %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  mutate(first_transaction = min(createDate),
         quarter = quarter(first_transaction, year = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(quarter) %>%
  summarize(clients = n())
```